# javascript iterate array through insertBefore

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make my code a bit more reusable.

Currently I am using:

```
var top_element = document.getElementById('main');

document.body.insertBefore(lightbox_overlay, top_element);
document.body.insertBefore(lightbox_border, lightbox_overlay);
document.body.insertBefore(lightbox_content, lightbox_border);
```

I would like to use an array and iterate through the items to do this, however:

```
var lightbox_elements = [];

lightbox_elements.push(lightbox_overlay, lightbox_border, lightbox_content);
```

Any ideas what the next steps are? Must be in plain JS..

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably use a `documentFragment` and `forEach` on your Array.

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

[ lightbox_overlay,
  lightbox_border,
  lightbox_content ].forEach(function(el) { frag.appendChild(el); });

document.body.insertBefore(frag, top_element);
```

---

You can shim older browsers with the patch from MDN.

- [`.forEach()` patch from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility)

---

Here's another solution that uses `.reduce()` instead.

```
[ lightbox_overlay,
  lightbox_border,
  lightbox_content ].reduce(function(prev, curr) { 
                               return document.body.insertBefore(curr, prev); 
                            }, top_element);
```

Since `prev` is always the last return value *(or the seeded value for the first iteration)*, and since `insertBefore` returns the `curr` item inserted, for each iteration, the `prev` is always the last `curr`.

- [`.reduce()` patch from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Compatibility)